# iptables: Allowing multicast & other traffic on LAN, not to WAN

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have a Linux 3.10 machine functioning as a NAT router between the `wlan0` LAN and the `eth0` WAN.  I would like to allow all communication between machines on the LAN (they are trustworthy) and allow them to connect outward as much as they please, but disallow all unsolicited inbound traffic to both the router and the NATted machines.

I would also like to block all outbound multicast traffic from both the router and the LAN machines, as the LAN administrator has yelled* at me for multicast traffic from my machine before.

My `iptables.rules` file looks like this:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sun Apr 20 21:38:37 2014
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [23:2184]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wlan0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Apr 20 21:38:37 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sun Apr 20 21:38:37 2014
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1643:178375]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1:60]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Apr 20 21:38:37 2014
```

How do I modify it so that LAN clients (and the router!) can communicate with each other?  Does the `OUTPUT` rule filter all multicast leaving for the WAN like I want?

*not actually *yelled* but close enough

Comment: *"disallow all inbound traffic to both the router and the NATted machines"* I *assume* that you really mean "inbound traffic not related to an established connection"; correct? (That's basically what a `-m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` rule does.)

Comment: Yes, good point. "Disallow all *unsolicited* inbound traffic" is better.  Edited.

Comment: Most multicast traffic on LANs is link-local, the kind routers and NAT gateways don't forward. Are you really doing routable multicasts that you need to worry about? Could you consider using non-routable multicast addresses for that traffic?

Comment: Non-routable multicast is fine, although I wasn't aware of the distinction, @Spiff.

Comment: Okay, then just keep your multicast destination addresses in the subnet-local 224.0.0.0/24 (224.0.0.0 – 224.0.0.255) range, and you probably won't need a specific rule to keep them from being forwarded.

Comment: I'd rather *block* routable traffic to prevent misconfigured devices from sending traffic.